# Spyder matplotlib plot not showing up - Mute inline plotting unticked

Tags: matplotlib, plot, spyder

In Spyder, IDE version 5.4.3, I am not getting any plot in the plot window.

I am running the simple code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xdata = np.linspace(start=-2*np.pi,stop=2*np.pi,num=50)
ydata = np.sin(xdata)
plt.plot(xdata,ydata)
```

The plot shows up in Google Colab, but not in Spyder.

I tried the following:

1. Verify that the Mute inline plotting is unticked
2. Under Tools -> Preferences -> IPython console -> Graphics -> Graphics Backend is set to Automatic
3. Updated the matplotlib through conda update matplotlib spyder
4. Restarted the kernel
5. Tried to add `plt.show()` at the end of the file

Nothing worked so far.

Comment: The plot should be a separate window. You don't see it pop up on the task bar? The issue is not reproducible as described. It will plot inline if inline is selected in the preferences.

Comment: Thanks Trenton,  I must have missed the pop-up late night or restarting the computer helped. The simple example is working now.

Comment: I would go ahead a delete this question. Glad it’s working